# Crash when OkHttp requests incorrect links

Tags: android, url, okhttp

When I asked for a link using OKHttp, it crashed because it wasn't the right link, how do I capture the crash, and I'm not sure if there will be any of these wrong links in the future. I need to capture him to avoid program crashes

this article is generated through translation tools, if you don't understand, please let me know.

```
try {
     val request = Request.Builder()
         .url("http://pic1.nipic.com|/2008-12-30/200812308231244_2.jpg ")
         .build()
     val client = OkHttpClient
         .Builder()
         .build()

     client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val s = response.body().toString()
                println(s)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
```

I wish I could capture it and avoid the crash.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 21: http://pic1.nipic.com|/
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.uri(HttpUrl.java:386)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextProxy(RouteSelector.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.<init>(RouteSelector.java:63)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.<init>(StreamAllocation.java:101)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 21: http://pic1.nipic.com|/
    at libcore.net.UriCodec.validate(UriCodec.java:63)
    at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:395)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:205)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.uri(HttpUrl.java:379)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextProxy(RouteSelector.java:129) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.<init>(RouteSelector.java:63) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.<init>(StreamAllocation.java:101) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:112) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200) 
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Can you post your crash log here ?

Comment: I updated it. Please check the log

Comment: IIRC okhttp3 `Request.Builder()` throws if you supply it an invalid url. Please check you have the newest version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is because you passed a special character in the url which makes it to be corrupted. To avoid the crash you can simply remove the special characters from the url before executing the code:

```
url = url.replaceAll("[|?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can avoid the exception by using `try catch` block

```
    private fun testing() {
        val request = Request.Builder()
        try {
            val httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse("http://pic1.nipic.com|/2008-12-30/200812308231244_2.jpg")?.uri()
            httpUrl?.let {
                request.url(it.toURL())
            }
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("Testing", e.toString())
            return
        }


        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

        client.newCall(request.build()).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Log.d("Testing", e.toString())
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                Log.d("Testing", response.body().toString())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Refer below link for get more discussion 
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/543